# ASP.NET MVC Custom Route Constraint For AJAX Requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I create a custom route constraint that will only match AJAX requests?

In a controller I can use `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`.

How can I access `IsAjaxRequest` from my custom constraint? I've implemented the `IRouteConstraint` interface and the `Match()` method as follows:

```
public class IsAjaxConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext,
                      Route route, 
                      string parameterName,
                      RouteValueDictionary values,
                      RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {            
     // How can I check for an Ajax request here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add this to your route constraint, does the httpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() work?

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Request.IsAjaxRequest() is an extension method in System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: Thank you. Knew I was overlooking something simple.